# Losing divider in native-base Modal when styling

Tags: native-base

Using native-base [Modal](https://docs.nativebase.io/modal) and [theming](https://docs.nativebase.io/next/customizing-components). See their [theme/components/modal.ts](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/components/modal.ts) for a reference as to what components make up a Modal and their theme.

So I'm trying to change the modal theme colors like so:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  ...

  components: {
    ModalHeader: {
      baseStyle: {
        _dark: {
          bg: "gray.700",
          color: "warmGray.50",
        },
      },
    },
    ModalBody: {
      baseStyle: {
        _dark: {
          bg: "gray.700",
          color: "coolGray.300",
        },
      },
    },
    ModalFooter: {
      baseStyle: {
        _dark: {
          bg: "gray.600",
          color: "text.50",
        },
      },
    },
    ModalCloseButton: {
      baseStyle: {
        _dark: {
          _icon: {
            color: "coolGray.100",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I want to give the divider a color of `gray.600` (the same as `ModalFooter`). However, I don't see `ModalDivider` as a component to color. Furthermore, the divider is no longer visible once I apply the above theme:
[my modal with theme applied and missing divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrBsa.png). I tried also coloring `ModalContent` but that did not help either.

Ideally, I'd like the divider to be seen like in their docs but with my colors.
Here is their modal in dark mode:
[native-base xl modal in dark mode where you can see the divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEXFI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in borderColor for ModalHeader. Change it like so:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  ...
  components: {
    ModalHeader: {
      ...
      baseStyle: {
         ...
        _dark: {
          ...
          borderColor: "blue.500",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```